# execute.sql files on a oracle DB in shell script

Tags: java, oracle, docker, sqlplus

I want to execute `.sql` files which are written with sql*plus commands on a oracle DB from a shell script.

An example of one `.sql` file you can see below:

```
  SET DEFINE OFF;

  -- Changeset om-core/om-core.sys.db-changelog.xml::om-core-createUser.24.0.0::mlo
  -- Creating om-dashboard schema/user
  CREATE USER omcore27 IDENTIFIED BY omcore;
  GRANT CONNECT TO omcore27;
  GRANT CREATE TABLE TO omcore27;
  GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO omcore27;
  GRANT CREATE ANY INDEX, SELECT ANY TABLE TO omcore27;
  GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO omcore27;
  GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO omcore27;
  GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO omcore27;
  GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQADM to omcore27;
  GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQ to omcore27;
  ALTER USER omcore27 QUOTA UNLIMITED ON SYSTEM;
  GRANT SELECT ON SYS.DBA_RECYCLEBIN TO omcore27;
  GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_AQIN to omcore27;
  GRANT select on v_$sysmetric to omcore27;
  GRANT select on dba_hist_sysmetric_summary TO omcore27;
  GRANT create job TO omcore27;
  GRANT create external job TO omcore27;

  -- Changeset om-core/om-core.sys.db-changelog.xml::om-core-grantAQ.24.0.0::mlo
  begin
            DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE (privilege => 'ENQUEUE_ANY', grantee => 'omcore27', admin_option => FALSE);
            DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE (privilege => 'DEQUEUE_ANY', grantee => 'omcore27', admin_option => FALSE);
            DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE (privilege => 'MANAGE_ANY', grantee => 'omcore27', admin_option => FALSE);
        end;/
```

So I need a shell command to execute above `.sql` file in on oracleDB.

I already tried to do that with a java program and then run that program `.jar` from my shell script, but I get that Error:

```
 Line: SET DEFINE OFF;
 *** Error : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

This is the sourecode of my DBScriptRunner class:

```
public class DBScriptRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String pathname = args[0];
            System.out.println("path name: " +pathname);
            executeScript(pathname);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void executeScript(String scriptFilePath) throws IOException, SQLException {
        // initialize script path
        // String scriptFilePath = "e:/script.sql";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        Connection con = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            // create connection
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:1521/romdb", "user",
                    "pwd");
            statement = con.createStatement();
            // initialize file reader
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(scriptFilePath));
            String line = null;
            // read script line by line
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // execute query
                if (line.startsWith("--")|| line.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("comment line or empty line: " + line);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Line: " + line);
                    statement.execute(line);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("*** Error : "+e.toString());  
            System.out.println("*** ");  
            System.out.println("*** Error : ");  
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // close file reader
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
            // close db connection
            if (con != null) {
                con.commit();
                con.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why aren't you just calling SQL\*Plus from your shell script? I don't get why you are trying to involve Java here?

Comment: because i'm not to familiar with shell script. can you tell me how i can to call SQL*plus in shell script please. THX

Answer (score 2):

Your script just needs to call SQL*Plus itself. Assuming the Oracle-related environment variables are set up already in the shell you'll call this from, the basic format is:

```
sqlplus -l -s user/pwd@hostname:1521/romdb @your_script.sql
```

or if your script doesn't have an `exit` at the end, with redirection instead:

```
sqlplus -l -s user/pwd@hostname:1521/romdb < your_script.sql
```

The `-l` flag prevents it reprompting for credentials if the supplied ones don't work for any reason, which can be particularly useful when running the script unattended. The `-s` flag suppresses the SQL*Plus banner and echoing of the commands as they are run.

You can then adapt and extend that in many ways, e.g. to set up the environment within the script, to add capture of the output to a log file, or to hide the login credentials from the command line so they aren't visible to `ps`, etc. The latter might look like:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
connect user/pwd@hostname:1521/romdb
@your_script.sql
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, i have another issue, i get :   `sqlpl: command not found`. So at the end my script should create a test environment automatically, and i don't know if other people, who want to use that script have already installed sqlplus or not. Do you have any idea if there is a docker image for sqlplus which I can run in my script to be able to use sqlplus?!

Comment: I don't know anything about Docker. There is an [instant client](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html) you can install easily. And the script can set up the environment to point to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below bash script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
username="username"
password="XXXXXXXXXXX"
db_ip="ipaddress"
port="1521"
sid=""
schema="schema"


echo "

select * from $schema.$tablename ;
## you can place all your queries here.
commmit;
exit
" | sqlplus -s "$username/$password@$db_ip:$port/$sid"
```

Hope it helps.

As shown above your can append your `.sql` file to `sqlplus` command as below

`sqlplus -s "$username/$password@$db_ip:$port/$sid @script.sql"`

Comment: thanks. But my queries are in a .sql file (see above). how can I execute the whole file?